# Angular Reactive Forms for property grid

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-controlvalueaccessor

Using Angular 12, I want to validate and detect changes in a list.

I have a property grid (a table of key/value pairs, listing properties with editable values, but each value can be of a different type, string/boolean/int/etc.).

I want to add validation and changes detection for that property grid.

Validation should happen for each item and the changes detection only needs to occur for the list as a whole (not caring which row/item was changed).

I've built something like this:

```js
export class InnerSetting {
  key!: string;
  displayName!: string;
  originalValue?: string;
  value?: string;
  type!: PropertyTypeEnum; //string | int | boolean | ...
  validation?: string;
  minValue?: number;
  maxValue?: number;
  isNullable!: boolean
}
```

```js
constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      properties: new FormArray([])
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.settings.forEach(item => this.formArray.push(this.formBuilder.group(
      {
        key: [item.key],
        type: [item.type],
        name: [item.displayName],
        value: [ item.value, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)] ], //Depends on type and validation stuff, will be added later.
        originalValue: [ item.originalValue ]
      }
    )));

    //Not sure which of these will work, so added both for now.
    this.form.valueChanges.pipe(debounceTime(500)).subscribe(changes => {
      this.areChangesDetected = changes != null;
    });

    this.formArray.valueChanges.pipe(debounceTime(500)).subscribe(changes => {
      this.areChangesDetected = changes != null;
    });
  }

  get formArray() {
    return this.form.controls.properties as FormArray;
  }
```

Before using a `Form`, I was just using a `InnerSetting` list, so bear in mind that I just started replacing the list with the form.

The `setting` property was an `InnerSetting` object.

```html
<form [formGroup]="form" class="group-wrapper">
  <div class="d-flex item-row" *ngFor="let setting of formArray.controls; let i = index">
    <div class="item flex-fill d-flex" [ngSwitch]="setting.type" [formGroupName]="i">
      <span>{{setting.name}}</span>

      <select *ngSwitchCase="'boolean'" class="flex-grow-1" name="role" id="role-select" [(ngModel)]="setting.value">
        <option [value]="'0'">False</option>
        <option [value]="'1'">True</option>
      </select>

      <div contenteditable *ngSwitchDefault class="flex-grow-1" type="text" [id]="setting.key" [innerText]="setting.value"></div>
    </div>

    <button class="remove-relation" (click)="reset(setting)">
      <fa-icon [icon]="faUndo"></fa-icon>
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

---

### Issues

Since I need to display different elements based on the setting type (boolean, string, number, etc). How can I access that information from the `formArray.controls`?

Also, how can I bind to non-standard input controls such as my `div` with a `contenteditable`?

---

### Edit

I noticed that the `formArray.controls` is an array of `FormGroup` and that I can access the values in `this.formArray.controls[0].controls['name'].value`.

Now the issue is setting that control to the fields (select or div or input) based on the type.

Comment: Here `*ngFor="let setting of formArray.controls;` your setting is a `FormGroup`. If you want to access `displayName` from `setting`, you could do `setting.get('displayName').value`. If you could provide it on stackblitz.com i can help more properly

Comment: To bind formControl to div with `contenteditable` you need to create custom formControl by implementing `https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor` interface

Comment: Thanks, it worked by using the `setting.get('name').value` accessor. The issue now is binding the control to the inputs and special inputs. I'll take a look at the link above.

Comment: I tried to use `[formControl]="setting.get('value')"` but it complains that `AbstractControl | null` is not assignable to `FormControl`.

Comment: The problem is when you get from FormGroup you will get `AbstractControl` not  FormControl because your `setting` FG dont know its FormControl. It just returns AbstractControl which we can't assign to `[formControl]`. Can you share it on stackblitz,

Comment: try using `formControlName='value'` instead of `[formControl]="..."`

Comment: @navnath Here you go: https://angular-ivy-aeszmb.stackblitz.io

Comment: Yes, I was using `formControlName="value"` before, and it was just returning that the property was not being found.

Comment: Check this. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vrcpgy?file=src%2Fapp%2F 
 is it okayapp.component.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your template will look like this

```
<form [formGroup]="form" class="group-wrapper">
  <div
    formArrayName="properties"
    class="d-flex item-row"
    *ngFor="let setting of settingFG; let i = index"
  >
    <div
      class="item flex-fill d-flex"
      [ngSwitch]="setting.get('type').value"
      [formGroupName]="i"
    >
      <!-- <span>{{ setting.get('name').value }}</span> -->

      <select
        *ngSwitchCase="'boolean'"
        class="flex-grow-1"
        name="role"
        id="role-select"
        formControlName="value"
      >
        ...
      </select>
      // custom div form control
      <div-control *ngSwitchDefault formControlName="value"></div-control>

    </div>

    <button class="remove-relation" (click)="reset(setting)">X</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Helper method to get array of FormGroup

```
 get settingFG(): FormGroup[] {
    return this.formArray.controls as FormGroup[];
  }
```

To add FormControl to div we need to implement [ControlValueAccessor](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor)

```
export const DIV_VALUE_ACCESSOR: any = {
  provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
  useExisting: forwardRef(() => DivController),
  multi: true,
};

@Component({
  selector: 'div-control',
  providers: [DIV_VALUE_ACCESSOR],
  template: `<div contenteditable #div (input)="changeText(div.innerText)" [textContent]="value"><div>`,
})
export class DivController implements ControlValueAccessor {
  value = '';
  disabled = false;
  private onTouched!: Function;
  private onChanged!: Function;

  changeText(text: string) {
    this.onTouched(); // <-- mark as touched
    this.value = text;
    this.onChanged(text); // <-- call function to let know of a change
  }
  writeValue(value: string): void {
    this.value = value ?? '';
  }
  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onChanged = fn; // <-- save the function
  }
  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.onTouched = fn; // <-- save the function
  }
  setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean) {
    this.disabled = isDisabled;
  }
}
```

*Don't forget to add in declaration array in the module.

[Full Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vrcpgy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Works nicely, thanks!

Comment: I just need to fix the `<div contenteditable>`, because in each text change, the text caret position is lost (i.e., moves to position 0).

Comment: I don't see that problem at my side

Comment: Oh, it only happens on pressing Enter. The caret is moved to position 0 in `changeText()`, I believe.

Comment: Solved using this directive https://github.com/KostyaTretyak/ng-stack/blob/master/projects/contenteditable/src/lib/contenteditable.directive.ts